# Backbone filter products in each category ( Filter parameter will be category name )

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have two collection views. This views render each object from products.json and second each from categories.json to `<li><%= title %></li>`.
Now I wanna render each category include every product from category...

**// !ALL CATEGORIES VIEW**

```
App.Views.Categories = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'categories',
    initialize: function() {
      this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);  
    },
    render: function() {
      this.collection.each( this.addOne, this );
      return this;
    },
    addOne: function(category) {
        var categoryView = new App.Views.Category({ model: category });
        this.$el.append(categoryView.render().el);
    },
});
```

**// !SINGLE CATEGORY VIEW**

```
App.Views.Category = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'category',
    template: template('allCategoryTemlate'),
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.on('destroy', this.unrender, this);
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
      return this;
    },
});
```

**// !ALL PRODUCTS VIEW**

```
App.Views.Products = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'products',
    initialize: function() {
      this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);  
    },
    render: function() {
      this.collection.each( this.addOne, this );
      return this;
    },
    addOne: function(product) {
        var productView = new App.Views.Product({ model: product });
        this.$el.append(productView.render().el);
    },
});
```

**// !SINGLE PRODUCT VIEW**

```
App.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'product',
    template: template('allProductTemlate'),
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.on('destroy', this.unrender, this);
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
      return this;
    },
});
```

**My products:**

```
[   
    {"product_id": 1, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 1", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 2, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 2", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 3, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 3", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 4, "category": "CATEGORY2", "title": "Product 4", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 5, "category": "CATEGORY2", "title": "Product 5", "price": 12}
]
```

**My categories:**

```
[
    {"category_id": 1, "value": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Category 1"},
    {"category_id": 2, "value": "CATEGORY2", "title": "Category 2"},
]
```

Example what I need:

```
Category 1
    - Product 1 
    - Product 2 
    - Product 3 

Category 2
    - Product 4 
    - Product 5
```

This is very important for my application, so I will be very heppy for every opinion.
Can I make something like :

```
var filtered = products.filter(function(product) {
    return product.get('category') == 'and there I need value from category ?';
});
```

Or in template something like :

```
<% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>
    <%= category.get('title') %>
    <li><%= title %></li>

    <% _.filter(products, function(product){ %>
        <%= return product category == value; %>

            <%= product.get('title') %>

            <% }); %> 
        <% }); %>

    <% }); %> 
<% }); %>
```

Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple filtering, use "where":

```
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var products = new Products(
    [ {"product_id": 1, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 1", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 2, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 2", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 3, "category": "CATEGORY1", "title": "Product 3", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 4, "category": "CATEGORY2", "title": "Product 4", "price": 12},
    {"product_id": 5, "category": "CATEGORY2", "title": "Product 5", "price": 12} ]
);
var cat1 = products.where({'category': 'CATEGORY1' });

console.log(cat1);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer !! Yes this is working but I need to crate filter for every category. And my categories will be dynamic So I need something like View where I will have data from categories collection and products collection. And after that I can in template do product filter based on name of category ...but I don't know how I can do this :/

Comment: @MatejMarko: Are you looking for [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) which is one of the [Underscore methods mixed into Backbone collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)?